# Como executar um procedimento somente uma vez?

Tags: delphi, microsoft-access

Montei um gerador de pagamentos que pega vários dados e salva em uma tabela do banco, o problema é que usei o evento OnActivate do Form, então cada vez que volta para o form inicial, o procedimento é executado novamente, sendo que esses dados só devem ser inseridos uma vez ao dia(pagamento referente ao dia atual). Alguma dica de como executar isso somente quando o programa for inicializado pela primeira vez ao dia(levando em conta que o usuário pode fechar e abrir novamente)?

```
procedure TForm3.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
dataa,dataontem,datatrunc : TdateTime;
year,month,day :word;
mm,dd ,a,btext,datatext:string;
b,c,i:integer;
valorMens:real;
Soma:Double;



begin

    datatrunc:=Trunc(dataa);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Gerar Pagamento Mensalidade
// ------------------------------------------------------------------



  i:=0;

  a:=stringgrid2.RowCount.ToString();
  c:=strtoint(a);
  edit5.Text:=inttostr(c);
  datatext:=datetimetostr(datatrunc);

  Form1.ADOQueryMens.Close;
  Form1.ADOQueryMens.Filter:=('Data='+ QuotedStr(datatext));
  Form1.ADOQueryMens.Filtered:=true;
  Form1.ADOQueryMens.open;



  if Form1.ADOQueryMens.FieldByName('Data').IsNull then
    begin


      if c>0 then
        begin
          while i<c do
            begin
              b:=strtoint(stringgrid2.Cells[0,i]);
              btext:=inttostr(b);

              adoQueryAluno.Close;
              adoQueryAluno.Filter:=('Código='+ QuotedStr(btext));
              adoQueryAluno.Filtered:=true;
              adoQueryAluno.open;

              Soma:= 0;
              ADOQueryAluno.First;

              while not ADOQueryAluno.Eof do
                begin
                  Soma:= Soma + AdoqueryAlunoValor.Value;
                  ADOQueryAluno.Next;
                end;
                valorMens:=Soma;
              Form1.AdoTableMensalidade.Open;
              Form1.AdoTableMensalidade.Insert;

              Form1.AdoTableMensalidade.FieldValues['CodAluno']:=b;
              Form1.AdoTableMensalidade.FieldValues['Valor']:=valorMens;
              Form1.AdoTableMensalidade.FieldValues['Data']:=Trunc(dataa);
              Form1.AdoTableMensalidade.FieldValues['Pago']:=false;

              Form1.ADOTableMensalidade.Post;
              Form1.ADOTableMensalidade.Close;
              Form1.ADOTableMensalidade.Open;

              i:=i+1;

            end;
        end;
       Form1.ADOQueryMens.Filtered:=false;

    end;
end;
```

Isso executa no OnActivate do Form, e faz a inserção dos valores na Tabela Mensalidade, quanto a isso está tudo ok e ele insere certinho... Mas ele executa toda vez que volta no form inicial, o que é o problema.

Comment: Faça uma consulta verificando se foi efetuado o lançamento na data atual, caso não retornar nada você sabe que deve ser feito o lançamento caso retorne significa que o lançamento já foi efetuado.

Comment: Por consulta você quer dizer um query em sql ou que? Assim ficou muito generalizado..

Comment: @DenerCarvalho poderia exemplificar por favor?

Comment: Se você estiver trabalhando com banco de dados, pode fazer uma pesquisa. Mais sugiro vc acrescentar mais informações a pergunta. Por exemplo: O código que esta no evento OnActive o que ele faz?

Comment: Adicionei o código, o que deve acontecer é ele ser ativado somente uma vez ao dia, e não cada vez que o Form principal é acessado.

Comment: conforme o @DenerCarvalho disse, você pode fazer uma query retornando um campo do banco pra ver se já foi executado a procedure, se o campo retornar nulo/vazio, você preenche esse campo no banco e assim ele vai executar somente uma vez a procedure, mesmo se fechar ou abrir o programa

Comment: Mas e se houver dados de outros dias? Esse campo poderia ser a data atual? Pois pode haver vários dados do mesmo dia.. Mas só serão inseridos se não houver nenhum nesse mesmo dia, certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segui as dicas do @ThiagoFriedman e @DenerCarvalho e funcionou, criei um filtro para a tabela Mensalidade usando a data atual e a partir dela verifiquei se tinha algum dado já inserido, e então via se deveria inserir ou não, conforme segue o código acima, foi corrigido está funcionando.